# Find matching tag items in table from string array using linq

Tags: sql, arrays, linq, entity-framework, entity

I have a `SQL` table of tags like this:

```
Id   |  Tag
-----------------
1    |  car
1    |  red
1    |  sport
2    |  car
2    |  red
2    |  SUV
```

And I want to retrieve ONLY the ID for exact matching search strings. So, using LINQ, I'd like to query for:
"car,red"

and have it return: 1 and 2.

Then searching for `"car,red,sport"` would return 1 only.

I'm not sure at all how to do this using LINQ. If I do the following (using EF context and table as example):

```
string[] tags = {"car","red","sport"}
var query = context.CarTags.Where(a => tags.Contains(a.Tag)).Select(s=>s);
```

...will of course return both 1 & 2.

So, how do I do this using LINQ?

Comment: And what if you will search for *sport* and *SUV*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string[] tags = {"car","red","sport"}

var query = context.CarTags
                   .GroupBy(a => a.Id)
                   .Where(g => tags.All(t => g.Any(a => a.Tag == t)))
                   .Select(g => g.Key);
```

I'm not sure if it's gonna work with LINQ to Entites, but would definitely give it a try.

All methods used are listed as `supported` within [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx) list, so should work. But even if it is, I would probably check the generated SQL to make sure it's not over-complicated and not very effective.

Comment: It works kind of...but it doesn't work if I query by {"car","red"}. It returns no results.

Comment: Ah, wrong `Where` statement. Check it now. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @user2566049 Just of being curious. Could you post the SQL that is being generated by LINQ to Entities for that query? :)

Comment: Well I would love to but it is "too long by 1096 characters"! I can email to you if you like

Comment: It would be great. My email should be visible to you on my profile here, on SO, or on my website (linked in the profile as well). Thanks!